# Building Python against Openssl 3.0 in nonstandard location

Tags: python, openssl

I have successfully source compiled OpenSSL 3.0 and installed it in `/some/dir` via the following sequence:

```
$ wget https://github.com/openssl/openssl/archive/refs/tags/openssl-3.0.7.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf openssl-3.0.7.tar.gz
$ cd openssl-openssl-3.0.7/
$ ./Configure CC=clang --prefix=/some/dir --openssldir=/some/dir
'-Wl,-rpath,$(LIBRPATH)'
```

I then try to build Python3.11 on top of it via:

```
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.1/Python-3.11.1.tgz
$ tar -xvf Python-3.11.1.tgz
$ cd Python-3.11.1/
$ ./configure CC=clang --with-openssl-rpath=auto --with-openssl=/some/dir
checking for openssl/ssl.h in /some/dir... yes
checking whether compiling and linking against OpenSSL works... yes
checking for --with-openssl-rpath... auto
checking whether OpenSSL provides required ssl module APIs... no
checking whether OpenSSL provides required hashlib module APIs... no
checking for --with-ssl-default-suites... python
checking for --with-builtin-hashlib-hashes... md5,sha1,sha256,sha512,sha3,blake2
...
checking for stdlib extension module _md5... yes
checking for stdlib extension module _sha1... yes
checking for stdlib extension module _sha256... yes
checking for stdlib extension module _sha512... yes
checking for stdlib extension module _sha3... yes
```

However, when I build, I get the following error:

```
$ make
...
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_hashlib              _ssl                  _tkinter
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.


Could not build the ssl module!
Python requires a OpenSSL 1.1.1 or newer
Custom linker flags may require --with-openssl-rpath=auto
```

(FWIW, I have tried with and without `--openssl-rpath=auto`. I have also seen that [python seems to support it](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/83001).)

How can I build this successfully with OpenSSL 3.0? OpenSSL 1.1.1 does not emit this warning.

As an aside, `hashlib` seems to work anyway:

```py
>>> import hashlib
>>> m = hashlib.sha256()
>>> m.update(b"Nobody inspects")
>>> m.digest()
b'\xe7\xa3\xf8\x08\xcb\x06\x87\xfd6`\xe9V\xa5\xdf\x0f\x00\xe2>\xda\xc5e\x07i\xec5N\xe6p\xb6X\x85\x8c'
```

but `ssl` does not:

```py
>>> import ssl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/some/dir/Python-3.11.1/Lib/ssl.py", line 100, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
```

Comment: You are missing requirements, these: `checking whether OpenSSL provides required blah blah blah.. no` lines are your tip-off. Just search up those lines and you'll get answers on what you need to install. **Note:** they're usually not all in one spot so it might take a few searches and a few tries

Comment: Openssl is one package, no? If I build it, then I should have all the `blah blah blah`.

Comment: Yes, it's one package the usual work but to compile with it you usually need other stuff (which you can uninstall after compiling).
As an example, I recently compiled Vim9 and it wasn't enough to have `python3` to enable python, it also needed `python3-dev`.
Some, like Vim's `--with-x`, requires more than a single extra package.. Which I'm  guessing SSL is the same due to all the checks.

Comment: @Nealium: I have edited the question to provide more details about how I'm compiling OpenSSL. Given my reading of both the openssl docs and the Python docs, I believe the listed package is both necessary and sufficient, as is evidenced by OpenSSSL 1.1.1 succeeding. However, particular options might be incorrect.